# Preventing unwanted behaviors from other scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Some websites will show a popup when the user's mouse leaves the viewport. This is an extremely aggravating behavior that I would like to get rid of. My strategy was to write a TamperMonkey script that would get rid of or prevent this behavior. Unfortunately, nothing I have tried works.
Note : I am trying to make this script as universal as possible.

The event is being added like so (there could be other ways, but I haven't gotten to those yet) :

An object is initialized, in which this line is executed :

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', someHandler);
```

[Example](http://carlsednaoui.github.io/ouibounce/)

Here is what I tried :

- Straight up remove the event handler by name (in the interest of keeping this as universal as possible, that was actually my last attempt as I wouldn't necessarily know the event handler's name) :

  document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mouseleave', someHandler);

But this is giving me the following error : "someHandler is not defined", probably because someHandler is within an object and can't be accessed from the outside (am I missing something?)

- Then I figured I would try finding all the event listeners on a given object before dealing with the results :

  getEventListeners(document.documentElement)

But unfortunately, this method apparently only exists in the dev tools and [can't be accessed from TamperMonkey](https://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?t=1154)

- Then I thought "Maybe the Chrome console can run its own script on every page load?" But I couldn't find anything on this.
- My next thought was "If I can't remove it, I'll prevent it from firing!".

  document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', myOwnHandler);

  function myOwnHandler(e){
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }

But this isn't working either because I cannot get my event in early enough. I tell my TamperMonkey script to run as early as possible, and it still gets beaten to it. For stopImmediatePropagation() to work, my event needs to fire first (events are fired in the order the were added in).

Any clues on how to get one of these to work, or any other ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

p.s. sorry, can't get all the code to look right.

Comment: IMHO it's not worth to fight these practices. What if they add some code that, say, resets the malicious script every 1 or 2 seconds? The right thing to do is probably to just stop visiting the website. If you treat your users badly, your website will die away.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I just feel like this is becoming too widespread. Also, this usually happens on sites I don't visit often, but sometimes I follow a link to one of these sites and get hit with one of these, or a damn modal window!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't a learning exercise, and you just want to prevent this from happening, why not use an adblocker? uMatrix, for example, lets you block cookies/img's/scripts/frames/XHR's on a per domain basis, so those scripts won't get to register those annoying event handlers in the first place.

Comment: Well I use AdBlockPlus, but it seems it can only block external scripts. Is μMatrix different in that respect? That would be a viable option if the scripts were always from external sources, but if the script is hosted locally, I'm not sure I could target it specifically?

Comment: You could block scripts being served from someSite.com while visiting someSite.com if you wanted to, but that sometimes prevents necessary scripts from running. But popups and ads are typically served from separate domains. Do you have an example website that has the behavior you mentioned?

Comment: That is my worry - that I would prevent useful scripts from running. I will keep my eyes peeled and bring an example back when I see this happen again. There is still the example from the post (http://carlsednaoui.github.io/ouibounce/), but I will try to come back with an instance from the "real world".

Comment: Well here you go, that was easy :
http://www.cnbc.com/2015/12/17/turing-pharmaceuticals-ceo-shkreli-arrested-by-fbi-reuters.html / http://www.popularmechanics.com/home/interior-projects/how-to/g830/10-jobs-you-can-do-with-a-multitool/

Comment: I loaded both pages, and disabled my adblocker(s), and didn't get any popups. I switched to other tabs, and tried moving my mouse out of the browser window, still never got any popup ads. Anyways, as a side note, I'd recommend [uBlockOrigin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) over AdBlockPlus, and [uMatrix](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/umatrix/ogfcmafjalglgifnmanfmnieipoejdcf?hl=en) if you use Chrome. You can filter by subdomains too, so you could block ads.someDomain.com but allow content.someDomain.com.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Alrighty then, thanks for the alternative to ABP!